# Can I make Jenkins checking SVN every hour for change?

Tags: java, spring, svn, jenkins

Can I make Jenkins checking SVN every hour for change?  I am new to Jenkins and I am working on a number of java projects.  I would like to know if I can get Jenkins to wake up every hour and see if the project changes in SVN.. If the project did change can I have it do the build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins doesn't "wake up", it runs continuously. However, what you want is that it polls SVN at regular intervals. Configure the SVN plugin accordingly:

-> your-project -> configure -> build triggers -> poll scm -> "24 * * * *"

"24 * * * *" is a CRON expression that tells Jenkins to poll SVN every hour always 24min past.

Comment: how do I do it if I would like it to build once a day?

Comment: @techsjs2012, that depends... if _build once a day even if SVN didn't change_ then click "Build periodically" rather than "Poll SCM" otherwise set the SCM-poll pattern to "0 4 * * *" for every day at 4am.

Comment: wait so do you mean that POLL mean if nothing changes it will not build?

Comment: You can also use `@hourly` or `@daily` to get it to poll at those times, rather than entering a full cron expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with the use of [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) plug-in

After that **poll svn** as shown [HERE](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2012/01/31/polling-subversion-with-jenkins/)

Comment: I thought you don't need a plugin for subversion

Comment: Then perhaps Jenkins comes bundled with the plugin?